# Formulating an Energy Functional for a Heat Equation with Inequality Constraints

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am working on a problem involving a heat equation with specific boundary/initial conditions and a compatibility condition. The problem is as follows:

1. The heat equation with inequality:
   $$ u_t - \alpha u_{xx} \geq 0 $$
2. Boundary/Initial condition where $ u $ is bounded below by $ g $:
   $$u \geq g $$
3. Compatibility condition that must be satisfied:
   $$(u - g) (u_t - \alpha u_{xx}) = 0 $$

I am trying to understand how to formulate an energy functional for this system, which will respect the above conditions and allow me to find a function $ u $ that minimizes this functional.

What I am looking for is an appropriate energy functional that takes into account the boundary/initial conditions as well as the compatibility condition. I understand that for classical heat equations, the energy functional often includes terms like $ \frac{1}{2} \alpha |\nabla u|^2 $, but I am unsure how to incorporate the time-dependent term and the inequality and compatibility constraints into this energy functional framework.

Could someone guide me on how to construct such an energy functional? Additionally, I am interested in any references or textbooks that might provide a detailed explanation of such formulations.

Any assistance or direction towards relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.